# decoupling and integrating differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble with the process of decoupling. If I have
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-x+y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-x-y$$

I am trying to figure out how to solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ by decoupling the system so that I only have one variable but I can't seem to get anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute $d^2 x/dt^2$, giving

$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = - \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt}$$

Use the second equation to replace $\frac{dy}{dt}$ with an expression in x and y, and use the first equation to replace $y$ with an expression in $dx/dt$ and $x$. The result is a second order equation in x.

Edit: For clarity, this gives

$$x'' = -x' + y' = -x' + (-x - y) = -x' -x - y = -x' - x - (x' + x)$$

$$x'' = -2x' - 2x$$

Comment: and then from there how do I get back to the original $x(t)$ ?

Comment: After doing this, it's just a second-order linear ODE. The standard technique would be to write down the characteristic polynomial (in this case, it's $z^2 + 2z + 2$, if I'm not mistaken), solve for roots, and write down one solution for each root as is done [here](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-2ndOrderLinearEqns_Stu.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Assume we can write $x'$ as $Dx$ in which $D$ stands for the differntiation. So your system would be as follows:
$$
\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            Dx=-x+y \\
            Dy=-x-y 
        \end{array}
    \right.
\longrightarrow \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            (D+1)x+y=0 \\
            x+(D+1)y=0 
        \end{array}
    \right.$$ Now try to find find $x$ and $y$ from above by eliminating one of them first. For example, by multiplying the second equation by $-(D+1)$ and making a summation we have: $$y-(D+1)^2y=0$$ which is $$y-(y''+2y'+y)=0$$ or $$y''+2y'=0$$ This is a very simple second-order OE. Do the same way for finding a proper expression with respect to $x$ and...

Comment: Yours Hamchenin! :-D

Comment: +1, dear Babak! I missed you earlier, I think! (My day is starting out poorly $\ddot\frown$)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can write your system like so:
$$
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y \end{pmatrix}
   +\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y \end{pmatrix}
   =0.
$$
To effectively decouple the equations, you want the system to looke like
$$
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\begin{pmatrix}u\\v \end{pmatrix}
   +\begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\v \end{pmatrix}
   =0,
$$
so you need to diagonalize the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, find the eigenvalues $a$ and $b$, and the corresponding eigenvectors $u$ and $v$. In this case, we find $a=1+i$, $b=1-i$, $u=(1,-i)$ and $v=(1,i)$. The final system is thus
\begin{align}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}u+(1+i)u=0 \\
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}v+(1-i)v=0
\end{align}
with $u=x-iy$ and $v=x+iy$.
This is a somewhat more general method, although probably slightly not as effective for this particular problem, then the one T. Bongers suggested.